# Top caching libraries for .NET

Tags: .net, caching

What caching libraries would you consider to be the most important or useful for .NET?

I'm asking because I need to contact them to see they plan on supporting .NET 4.0's caching framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Appfabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) from Microsoft
[Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/coherence/index.html) from Oracle
[NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) from Alachisfot
[Memcached](http://memcached.org/) with .Net clients

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the ASP.NET cache, the only one I've seen in common use (and used myself) is Microsoft's own [Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649093.aspx) in the Enterprise Library.

Comment: That got promoted to be part of .NET 4.0. But the way its written it's just begging for other caching frameworks to use the same API.

Answer (score 3):

[NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)

[SharedCache](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/homepage.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[NCache] Alachisoft's NCache is More Powerful then Appfabric Try its free version[1](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)

Comment: I agree with @royaan here. NCache is much more faster and reliable than any other caching solution available for .NET. Plus, they also have JvCache for java, which is compatible with NCache in their upcoming version. That could prove to be useful in complex environments.