# Cache server for .NET(Example Memcached)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memcached

I am looking for cache server for .NET. What can you suggest? As i know memcached has provider for .net. Is it good enough to use for .net in production?

Comment: What is your use case?  What are you caching?  Are you looking for only free solutions, or can you consider commercial as well?

Comment: We used memcached with ASP.NET in production. You can give it a try

Comment: I want to decrease amount of requests to database. I need free solution.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. WHat can you say about Microsoft's own Caching Application Block in the Enterprise Library? Can it used for cache server? Or it is cache for one application or general cache for all applications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731.aspx) is another popular solution from Microsoft.

Comment: Can it be runned on the same server where we have web server? What about perfomance?

Comment: @F0rc0sigan, yes it can be on the same machine, but a caching server usually takes lots of memory so if you want scalability it would be better to be distributed over caching servers. All will depend on the load you are expecting. As a starting you could install it on the same server and if you begin to encounter higher user loads distribute it over different machines.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to run your cache server in Linux, you could use Redis, and use the BookSleeve library from .NET, this is what StackOverflow uses

http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/

Comment: Hi i want to run cache server on windows server.

Answer (score 3):

[Scale Out State Server](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/) is an excellent solution.  It's not free, but for [large-scale applications](http://highscalability.com/product-scaleout-stateserver-memcached-steroids), it's one of the best options that we found.

[NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) is another option, though I have no experience with it.

For enterprise scale (and budget) there's [Oracle's Coherence](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/Configuration+and+Usage+for+.NET+Clients).  It works extremely well, though it's extremely pricey.

Here's another SO question with some information that may or may not be helpful:
[Caching Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011441/caching-solutions)

Answer (score 2):

Memached is plenty good for production, probably best using the [enyim provider](http://memcached.enyim.com/).

[Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/memcached) provide a good web ui and easy memcached install on windows. Free if on a single server.  It's great to be able to monitor your cache instance.

They have paid for solutions but and their own server.

AppFabric as mentioned is another obvious candidate but not a mature as memcached.  AppFabric is an application server and can also provide distributed caching like membase

Answer (score 1):

See the post [Top caching libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823505/top-caching-libraries-for-net) for several options, including both free and commercial. The choice will vary based on your actual need.

Answer (score 0):

though there are numbers of third party caching solutions are available for .NET but if we narrow done the research based upon Google and word of mouth, it might be 
1) Memcached
2) Appfabric
3) NCache

firs two are free/open source software so they have some limitations in it, while on the other hand NCache has a lot to  offer as compared to others, but you have to buy it. but it has also a free version available called as NCache Express. below are two important links in this regard,

[Video on NCache Vs AppFabric](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CPi1QlskrU)

[Blog on NCache Vs AppFabric](http://distributedcaching.blog.com/2011/05/26/ncache-features-that-app-fabric-does-not-have/)