# What cache server for .NET is th best?(CSql, Memcached, NCache, Shared Cache, AppFabric)?

Tags: asp.net, caching, memcached, appfabric, ncache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cache server for .NET(Example Memcached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072560/cache-server-for-netexample-memcached)

I am  trying to choose cache server for my project that will be written on .NET. I found a list of servers:CSql, Memcached, NCache, Shared Cache, AppFabric. What is the best on your mind and why. Please share your expierence of using them.
Thanks,
Dima.

Comment: There is no definitive 'Best'. What are your needs? do you need it for a web server? a web farm? something else? are you looking for a free solution or are you willing to pay?

Comment: I need the best perfomance. And it have to work good as on web server as on web farm. And this software needs to have the simpliest installation on we hosting.